# Joystick not working as a mouse

Tags: usb, joystick

I have recently purchased a cyborg v.1 joystick.  I have also installed jstest-gtk. When I configure it, it connects to the joystick and interprets the movement, however, I have not been able to use the joystick as a mouse.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:
For most USB joysticks you can't just plug them in and use them as a mouse, you have to restart your computer with the joystick plugged in, the joystick SHOULD now work.